# gambit scheme - import functions from another file into current scope

Tags: scheme, gambit

I have the function `run` in file `run.scm`. I want to make `run` available in `test.scm`. How would I go about doing this in Gambit scheme?

I've already tried `(import "run.scm")`, but it just complained about `import` being an unbound variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gambit Scheme uses `include` not `import`.

Gambit Scheme does not come with modules as standard, for modules like you seem to be describing, you would have to use [Black hole](http://dynamo.iro.umontreal.ca/wiki/images/3/30/Black_Hole_Core.pdf), which is an extension of Gambit and needs to be installed and loaded separately or [Gerbil Scheme](https://cons.io/) which is built on gambit (so is nearly as fast I guess though I have never used it). Another scheme based on Gambit Scheme with modules is [LambdaNative](https://www.lambdanative.org/), Which has a unique "external" module system, and is designed mainly for writing mobile applications.

So with files `run.scm` and `test.scm` in the same folder.......

**run.scm**

```
(define (run .  args)
  (if (not (null? args)) 
      ( println args) 
      ( println "no args")))
```

**test.scm**

```
(include "run.scm")

(define (test-run . args)
  (if (not (null? args))
      (run args )   
      (println "run not tested")))
```

then from the interpreter (**gsi**)

```
>(load "test.scm")

>(test-run 1 2 3)  ; output  -> 123

>(run)  ; output  -> no args

>(test-run) ; output ->  run not tested
```